# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am doing the android tutorial on the [android site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

i keep getting these errors at the EditText: error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)  and Element Linearlayout must be followed by either attribute specification, `>` or `/>`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0DP"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0DP"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You were missing a closing `>` at the end of your LinearLayout element.